# IOS: how can I make a variable global

Tags: ios, variables, global

I need to get JSON file one time, when I enter to the class then I can use the result from another method.
In other words, How can I make this result as a Global?

I have a Drop Down menu as a table view and on clicking the button I execute 'selectClicked' function to view the tableview. 
So, I need to get the content for the  tableview from  the global variable in viewDidLoad method or another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways to do what you want to do, but you should also remember that Objective C is a superset of C, thus you can use normal C global variables.  Since I refer to my appDelegate quite often, I make a global variable in AppDelegate.h of it.  Just put it after the @end in your .h file, and include the .h file where you're using it. Like so:

```
@end


AppDelegate * appDelegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the singleton pattern: it's an extremely powerful way to share data between different parts of code without having to pass the data around manually.

Make your Json data receiving class as singleton and use the data from any part of your project. To know how to make and use singleton: Read any tutorial from the blogs :[link](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)